# Mac mini server, openvpn

Tags: mac, vpn

I have a Mac mini Server 10.8 (intel i7) acting as server with an Airport Extreme as the router with a static IPaddress and OpenVPN (tunnelblick).

How can I get access to the file server on my mac mini server via OpenVPN from a remote location ?

Client machine is on Win7, iOS, Linux (rpm. deb.), Android etc.

We must be able to run 10 parallel connections inside the tunnel.

Answer (score 0):

As long as your VPN is connected and thus working properly, the method should be the same as if you were at that remote (VPN'd) location.